Particle and momentum Flow for complex scalar or fermion field
When i look at complex scalar fields or fermion fields, i have my $\psi^\dagger$ as my anti particle and $\psi$ as my particle, same for $\phi^\dagger$ and $\phi$. When i now draw the Feynman diagrams i have the contractions between particle and anti particle. I can draw the fermion flow in the way i like but i am now wandering, when i contract $\psi$ with $\psi^\dagger$ in which direction goes the momentum flow? Is this then an anti particle flowing or a particle as anti particles have the momentum flow opposite to the particle flow?
